# Как определить причину падения приложения, если краш происходит при выполнении кода в отдельном потоке qthread

Tags: qt5, отладка, dump

есть огромное приложение, которое падает спустя несколько дней/часов работы. в приложении постоянно работает один поток qthred в цикле где и происходит основной код, и где скорее всего и находится причина краша. когда я искусственно делаю ошибку в коде в функции main, или в любом другом месте в основном потоке (не в qthread) то дебагер mvsc с помощью дампа созданного во время падения - указывает мне строку, по вине которой произошел краш. но если ошибка произошла где-нибудь в потоке thread то дебагер выдает подобный стек вызовов: `[Внешний код]
Qt5Core.dll!QEventDispatcherWin32::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags)Строка 657    C++
qwindows.dll!QWindowsGuiEventDispatcher::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags)Строка 75   C++
[Внедренный фрейм] Qt5Core.dll!QEventLoop::processEvents(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags)Строка 138    C++
Qt5Core.dll!QEventLoop::exec(QFlags<enum QEventLoop::ProcessEventsFlag> flags)Строка 225    C++
Qt5Core.dll!QCoreApplication::exec()Строка 1364 C++
MyApp.exe!main(int argc, char * * argv)Строка 1620  C++
MyApp.exe!WinMain(HINSTANCE__ * __formal, HINSTANCE__ * __formal, char * __formal, int __formal)Строка 98   C++
[Внешний код]`
как быть, что делать? как найти причину краша с помощью дебагера и дампа памяти, если этот самый краш прозошел в исполняемом в потоке qthread коде?

Comment: Сделать копию проекта. Потом выкидывать код по очереди и ждать когда падения прекратятся. Так можно понять на чем именно падает.

Comment: проект огромный, и краш происходит очень-очень-очень редко, неужели нельзя как-то определить конкретную строку в коде который исполняется в потоке qthread

Comment: Запустите код этого потока отдельно, в отдельном проекте. Добейтесь сбоя. Потом, выбрасывая каждый раз половину кода, найдете место сбоя. Дихотомия довольно быстро сходится, спасибо Создателю. Вобщем смысл в том, чтобы максимально упростить проект и при этом не потерять сбой.

Comment: да, спасибо за комментарий, я именно так и сделал, а точнее я просто разместил весь код в основном потоке..., да я получаю мертвое gui, но за-то создав искусственный краш, я смог найти причину до пампу в дебагере.